# PHP parse_ini_file relative path?

Tags: php, file, parsing, ini

I have this code:

```
$test = parse_ini_file("../data/test.ini");
```

test.ini is located back one directory and then forwards into the data folder.  But the problem I'm getting is parse_ini_file doesn't like when I make this relative link to the file, can anyone help me do this without making a absolute link to the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$test = parse_ini_file(realpath("../data/test.ini"));
```

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) link

Or you could just use the absolute path directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but it doesn't seem to like that either :S, I get:Warning: parse_ini_file() [function.parse-ini-file]: Filename cannot be empty in...

Comment: Well, as the docs I pointed say, that means that `realpath` returned false. How are you calling your PHP file? What is your directory structure?

Comment: It starts at a index.php file which includes pages/admin.inc.php which is the script that loads up the ini file by going to ../data/test.ini

Comment: The path must be relative to **the file called by the browser**, NOT to the file in which `parse_ini_file` is called, in fact PHP automatically `chdir` to your `index.php` directory.